# Opening Django FileField in with both PIL & open(file,mode) at the same time

Tags: django, file, python-imaging-library, django-models

I am having kind a wired problem with my code. 
I am uploading file from form, which i get `InMemoryUploadedFile`.

```
image_node = data['image_url'] # InMemoryUploadedFile
body = image_node.read()
# do whatever you like with the picture, 

pil_image = Image.open(image_node) # PIL image object. 
# i get error that Cannot identify image.
```

When I open PIL first, i works fine, and then `image_node.read()` fails.  I think i am missing some file object concept. Please find the semantic error.

Comment: Do you mean if you reverse the order things works fine?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this

```
image_node = data['image_url']
body = image_node.read()

# do stuff

image_node.seek(0)
pil_image = Image.open(image_node)
```

Comment: This worked, Thanks, Can you please let me know why was this case? why we need seek(0)?

Comment: Sure, beacuse it reads the file in stages, when you do image.read(10) it will return you only the first 10 bytes, and when you call it once again, it will return the NEXT 10 bytes, all the way till the end. this is so because sometime you want to read a very large file, you will then want to read it in stages. image.seek(0) simply rewinds it to the beginings, the first byte. i hipe i have explained it :)